# Angular ngFor only showing one name from the data in loop

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have this data in my component.ts file picked up from an api call

```
[ 
    [ 
        { 
            "name": "name one",
            "desc": "something here",
        },
        {
            "name": "name two",
            "desc": "something here",
        },
        { 
            "name": "another name",
            "desc": "something here",
        }
    ]
]
```

I then pass it to my component.html with:

```
this.mydata = [result];
```

**[result]** contains the data above.

Then I have the select:

```
<select name="list">
    <option *ngFor="let data of mydata; value="{{ data.name }}">{{ data.name }}</option>
 </select>
```

This problem I'm having is that the select is not populating any names

I added this: `{{ mydata | json }}` and I can see that the data is there as shown above.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the `{{ mydata | json }}`.

Comment: It should be `this.mydata = result[0];`

Comment: try with `this.mydata = result;`

Comment: You are currently wrapping your result array in another array. Simply use `this.mydata = result;`

Comment: The porblem should simply be that you have an array nested as a element of another array, so as John said *ngFor="let data of mydata[0]" should do the trick

Comment: Just remove extra bracket form result or use result[0] it should work, I dont know why its not working for you everyone suggested same.

Comment: its valid json, you dont just "remove brackets"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are creating one more array wrapper `[]`. It results in the way you posted like `[[...]]`. Instead remove the `[]` from here:

```
this.mydata = result; // <---actual data may look like this = [{}, {}, ...]
```

Comment: That is giving me: The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a nested array. so when you iterate over `myData` property, there is an array again and no `name` and `desc` is available.
try this:

```
this.mydata = result[0];
```

Comment: this.mydata = result[0] is giving my error: "Only arrays and iterables are allowed"

Comment: please console.log this.myData then i can better understand your problem

Comment: console is showing it like this: [ {}, {}, {} ]   and when expanded  0: {}   1: {}   2: {}

Comment: no soutlion works

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in assigning `mydata`.
Currently, `mydata` is the same as `result` value.
If you update as follows, then your code will work.

```
this.mydata = result[0];
```

or

```
const [result] = [ 
    [ 
        { 
            "name": "name one",
            "desc": "something here",
        },
        {
            "name": "name two",
            "desc": "something here",
        },
        { 
            "name": "another name",
            "desc": "something here",
        }
    ]
];
this.mydata = result;
```

Then show the data in angular code.

```
<select name="list">
    <option *ngFor="let data of mydata;" value="{{ data.name }}">{{ data.name }}</option>
 </select>
```

On your question, double-quote is missing when defining *ngFor.

Comment: this.mydata = result[0] is giving my error: "Only arrays and iterables are allowed"

Comment: then try this. (result as any[])[0];

Comment: That returns an error: Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: Then try like this. `(Array.from (result))[0]`

Comment: That returns: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

Comment: can you post the result correctly? the value of the `result`

Comment: Are you getting the result value from api response or? I need more info regarding `result` value.

Comment: The exact value is in the question ... maybe removing the 2 wrapping [] would work?

Comment: yes, then, everything will work. Remove the uotside wrapping []. Then it will work on template.